# Workflow Auto update lead owner from A queue to B queue

Tags: workflow

Quick question about the SF workflow. 
The request is, when the lead stays in A queue for more than 1 min, it will be automatically transferred to B queue.

I wrote a criteria like this：

```
Owner:Queue.DeveloperName = 'A_Queue' 
&& Lead_Created_Time_in_SFDC__c < NOW()-(1/1440)
```

However, after I created a lead and put it in A queue, and I waited for about three mins, nothing happended.

Based on what I've learned, salesforce flow can only be fired when the record is created or every time it is edited. So, my question is, is there any way we can update the lead owner without doing anything? No edit just wait, like what I've above :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use time based workflow to achieve this functionality.

For more information, refer [Time-Based Workflow FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)

Also,

> Salesforce doesn't display time-dependent action controls on the workflow rule edit page if you set the workflow rule evaluation criteria to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just realized I can use time based action. Thanks a lot Santanu.